# iOS WebRTC and QuaggaJS

Tags: ios, cordova, webrtc, quaggajs

I am working on an cordova Barcode Scanner app for mobile Devices. I am using the Framework QuaggaJS for Barcodescanning and the cordova-plugin-ioswebrtc to implement the webrtc functions to cordova. Its working fine on Android Devices and on local Web Browsers on PC, but if i want to use it on iOS I always getting the error "Failed to load ressource: file is directory".

I am initializing Quagga with the following settings:

```
{decoder:{readers:["code_93_reader"]},
 numberOfWorkers: 4,
 inputStream: 
 {
    name: "Live",
    type: "Livestream",
    target: document.querySelector('#scanner'),
    constraints:
    {
      width:{min:640},
      height:{min:480},
      facingMode: "environment"
    }
 }
}
```

The error Message does not describe where the error comes from so I am not sure if its a problem of quaggaJS or of the iOS WebRTC plugin of cordova. Does anyone has build a cordova app with QuaggaJS and can help me where these problem comes from?

If I am Running the getUserMedia Function in the console, i get to different Objects back. In normal iOS Browser the result is of type MediaStream and in the cordova app the result is of type Blob. In safari my app is working without problems, and the Blob Object has all attributes of MediaStream and more so that should not be a problem or?

Comment: Did you ever get this working. I'm currently creating a basic Cordova app to try and get QuaggaJS up and running on Android and iOS.

Comment: no i wrote a plugin which opened a camera view over the webview in iOS